# Replace non-breaking whitespace character in JSON data in SF Flow formula

Tags: visual-workflow, json

I have a Flow in Salesforce that parses a Long Text field with JSON data in it. The flow then uses the Unofficial SF JSON Mapping Component to map the data in the JSON into a collection variable. I have a formula that cleans up the JSON data prior to the mapping and it works except for the fact that some of the data has the '\u00A0' (non-breaking whitespace) character in the content (See example JSON data).

What's the best way to remove that '\u00A0'?

**Example JSON data:**
'''{"title":"List the Center or FCC you work at. \u00a0(If you do not work at a center of FCC, simply reply N/A)","value":"na"},{"title":"Do you participate in QRIS?","value":"No"},{"title":"CA Workforce\u00a0Registry","value":"No"}'''

**Complete formula in SF flow to clean up JSON data prior to passing into a text variable that is then mapped to the various relevant fields (Note that I tried several variations using JSENCODE including ' ' and '\u00a0'):**
'''SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(
left(right({!$Record.Zoom_Meeting_Registrant_Data_JSON__c},LEN({!$Record.Zoom_Meeting_Registrant_Data_JSON__c})-FIND("[",{!$Record.Zoom_Meeting_Registrant_Data_JSON__c})+1),LEN({!$Record.Zoom_Meeting_Registrant_Data_JSON__c})-FIND("[",{!$Record.Zoom_Meeting_Registrant_Data_JSON__c})),
'" "','" "'),
'"custom_questions":[{"title":"What county do you work in?","value"','"County"'),
'},{"title":"Are you center staff/Family Childcare Provider/other? (Please select the option that describes your work best?)","value"',',"StaffType"'),
'},{"title":"List the Center or FCC you work at.  (If you do not work at a center of FCC, simply reply N/A)","value"',',"CenterOrFCC"'),
'},{"title":"Do you participate in QRIS?","value"',',"QRIS"'),
'},{"title":"CA Workforce Registry","value"',',"WorkforceRegNumber"'),
'}],"status"',',"status"')'''